# Create a clickable box inside a style sheet

Tags: html, css

How do you implement a clickable box inside a style sheet on a web page?

The box will be created using a method such as this:

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><a class="page-button" href="/page/form.cfm" style="text-align:center;">Submit an Application</a></p>
```

Comment: Do you mean a checkbox? Looks like you want a checkbox for users to use prior to form submission?

Comment: You can’t create those in stylesheets themselves. Are you looking for a checkbox or submit button on a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the box (link) look similar to the Student Referral Form button on the [SMSU site](http://www.smsu.edu/admission/?id=10076) you provided, you can give the `.page-button` link class any background, text color, some padding, and no text decoration. For the `:hover` state, just use a background color lighter than the normal state’s.

```css
a.page-button {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.page-button:hover {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align:center;">
  <a class="page-button" href="/page/form.cfm" style="text-align:center;">Submit an Application</a>
</p>
```